# Staircase or steps effect with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, z-index

In the image below, the rows in the right side of image have some special effect i.e.they are appearing in different plains

Not sure what is the correct term for this but looks like stair case.
So my question is how to achieve this effect?

Tried using box-shadow but couldn't achieve this

[image: Stair case effect in image]

Comment: you could nest divs with a margin left of whatever step you want, but there are many ways to achieve this so I'm voting to close this as too broad

Comment: I am not exactly looking for a code. I am looking for the approach I should try

Comment: Which is essentially the same thing. Asking on SO is not doing research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a starting point for you:

```
<body>
<div id='stepContainer'>
    <div class='step'>step 1</div>
    <div class='step'>step 2</div>
   <div class='step'>step 3</div>
   <div class='step'>step 4</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And style it with

```
<style>
#stepContainer {
   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   background-color: white;
}
.step {
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   border-bottom: 12px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.step:nth-child(1) { height :100px; background-color: blue; margin-left: 20px;}
.step:nth-child(2) { height :100px; background-color: green;  margin-left: 40px;}
.step:nth-child(3) { height :100px; background-color: aqua;  margin-left: 50px;}
.step:nth-child(4) { height :100px; background-color: red;  margin-left: 60px;}
</style>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Awesome !! little difficult but an interesting solution !